# Do I need a database for my software?

Tags: database

I'm making a software as a personal project. The software is aimed to act like a personal diary which has to store lots of text and numbers. It'll not be connected to the internet in any manner, as of now.

My question is- Do I need a database based on SQL etc. or simple file-handling through C/C++ will do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It all depends on what you are going to do with the data.**

If you are just looking for a way to put away a portion of text and numbers, and being able to bring it back later a simple file-handler will be sufficient.

But if you are going to need relations between data sets, if you'd like to search the data in a quite efficient manner, or handle it in a more dynamic manner; a database might be your best bet.

Though you do not need to set up a daemon running MySQL, put it on a dedicated server, optimize the shit out of the disk IO etc etc.. that will probably be overkill by a thousand.

You will certainly get very far by just using SQLite which is a file based database driver, no socket connections are required, if there is only one user who is to access the database at a time it's a good solution.

**Documentation links**

- [**SQLite Documentation**](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html)
- **[Information about a 'flat file database'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database)**

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a database for what you describe, although depending on how you plan on developing your app, it might make things easier for you to use a database.  Certainly if you plan to go multi-user at some point a database will provide many features to facilitate this that would be prohibitive for you to build yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Is there always one and only one user of the data?  If so, something simple like a flat file or sqlite will work just fine.  If you need concurrency in access, use a database.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to define "lots of text and numbers".  If it gets too large then file storage alone may not be efficient enough.  Doesn't sound like that will be the case for personal data diary but it is a consideration in general.

Answer (score 0):

I would use both: files for `lots of text and numbers` and SQLite database to save some additional data, that is not recoverable from plain files (at least without using extended file attributes) such as rating, REAL (not read from FS) date of creation, tags etc.

Database storage will also allow you to backup these info, access and modify thing concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

If your application's conceptual model is going to have many different entities and different relations between them then the database will help you much, especially if you need to make various queries to your data.

I think SQLite is ideal for the application like you described.

Answer (score 0):

One point that seems to have been missed - don't get hung up on using a relational database (most of the suggestions are, reasonably sensibly, for embedded SQL databases).

It may be that a NoSQL style system with rather more flexibility in terms of the way that your data is stored is more appropriate - its hard to judge without a more detailed spec, but if it a diary with variable requirements depending on the entry rather than a rigid structure a system that stores key/value pairs in a flexible fashion might be a better match.

I'm not able to suggest embeddable NoSQL systems (I'm looking at [SterlingDB](http://sterling.codeplex.com/) but I'm a .NET developer and looking at stuff for Windows Phone 7)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple XML file is an option for your scenario?
Certainly if you work in C++ that would be easier (quicker) to implement then connecting to a database (sql seems like overkill for a diary imho).